# Factorization of Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices

In "A Convex Optimization Approach for Minimizing the Ratio of Indefinite Quadratic Functions over an Ellipsoid" (https://iew3.technion.ac.il/~becka/papers/RQfinal.pdf) they discuss the minimum generalized eigenvalue of symmetric matrix (see equation 2.4) and claim that it can be defined as $\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{B}^{-1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1/2})=\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})=\max\{\lambda:\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{B}\succeq0\}$ (see section 1.3). My question is, do we know that it always is possible to find a factorization $\mathbf{B}^{-1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1/2}=\mathbf{S}$ for every symmetric matrix $\mathbf{S}$? I know that is is possible to find a orthogonal $\mathbf{P}$ and a diagonal $\mathbf{D}$ such that $\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}^{\intercal}$, but that result is not strong enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

$S=I^{-1/2}SI^{-1/2}$ is such a factorisation. In general, given any $B\succ0$, you may take $A=B^{1/2}SB^{1/2}$.